# How to make very small rectangles visible on a large OpenGL screen?

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to draw millions of 2D small rectangles (eg, 150X150) on a very large openGL canvas (eg.500000X500000) with viewport (680X530).
Is there a way to make these relatively small rectangles some how visible on the screen without zooming in, such that the screen wouldn't look empty at first.

The following are my draw and reshape functions:

```
static void draw() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //draw millions of rectangles
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glRectf( 275240.0, 499860.0, 275380.0, 500000.0);
    glFlush();
}

static void reshape() {
    glViewport(0, 0, 680, 530);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D (0.0, 500000.0, 0.0, 500000.0);
}
```

Can anyone gives me some suggestion here.

Comment: Uh, sure, there is couple of ways around this (most primitive one would be to scale them a bit if they are really far), but considering your rectangles are like 1/5th of a pixel, no matter how you do it it's probably going to look like a mess :(

Comment: I think you've a conceptual misunderstanding; OpenGL doesn't have any units or a canvas. It's up to you to define some system for your world and then transform vertices accordingly to the canonical view volume for the primitives to show up on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a geometry shader.

Testing the area of quad, you could apply a scaling matrix, and maybe divide colour accordingly

Comment: How's that possibly solves the case when rectangle geometry size is 4% of a pixel?

Comment: computing a scalling matrix in your geometry shader based on eye distance will solve that. if dist is greater than a threshold, you scale the quad to have it bigger than a pixel

Comment: According to OP, it's all in 2D, so distance from Eye to Object is known in advance

Comment: right, so in geom shader the treshold should be apply to area of quad

Answer (score 1):

In your draw routine for each rectangle, check if zoomlevel is below a certain factor.

if it is, draw 2D point (GL_POINT) with size 4, otherwise (high zoomlevel) draw usual 2D rectangle.